# How can I use a value from MVC view in controlller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAJSF.png)

How can I use the value I get from an input on the view side in mvc?
For example, when I enter 30 from the input, I want to save it to the database by making various calculations with this value in the controller. I have specified a parameter as int a in the controller. I want to get this parameter by view. I will use this a value in the calculation after I receive it. I have given the picture of the code on the View side as a link above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectTiklaKazan.Models.Sınıf;
namespace ProjectTiklaKazan.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class DonusturController : Controller
    {
        Context c = new Context();
        // GET: Donustur
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int a, PuanBilgi p)
        {
            Users u = Session["UserID"] as Users;
            var toptohum = c.PuanBilgis.Where(x => x.UserID == u.UserID).ToList().Sum(x => x.PuanMiktar).ToString();
            if (toptohum.Count() !=0)
            {
                if (int.Parse(toptohum) >=30)
                {
                    if (a%30 ==0)
                     {
                        var tl = a * 0.00025;
                        p.PuanMiktar = -a;
                        p.TlMiktar = tl;
                        p.UserID = u.UserID;
                        p.Tarih = DateTime.Now;
                        c.PuanBilgis.Add(p);
                        c.SaveChanges();
                     }
                    else
                     {
                        TempData["DonusturmeMesaji"] = "Lütfen 30 ve katları olan";
                     }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["YetersizBakiye"] = "Yetersiz Bakiye. Sadece 30 ve 30 katlarını dönüştürebilirsiniz!";
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the value using the same name as your controller expects.  `@Html.TextBox("a", 0)`

Comment: Doing that kind of "work" in your controllers is suspect.

Comment: How suspicious. I do not understand